# How can I set a key binding to run two other key bindings?

Tags: key-bindings, auctex, commands

Specifically, I want the binding 'C-x C-a' to do 'C-x C-s' then 'C-c C-a'. (Context: I'd like to save my TeX document, then have AUCTeX render it.) How can I do this? I don't want to map 'C-x C-a' to any specific command, or to re-bind it to exactly one other thing, which is what most of the Google results turn up.

Comment: Why would you work against how things are commonly done in Emacs land?

Comment: Could it be that you actually want to re-bind `C-c C-a` and not `C-x C-a`?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [section 17](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html#Keyboard-Macros) of the emacs manual, on keyboard macros. Notice in particular [section 17.5](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Save-Keyboard-Macro.html#Save-Keyboard-Macro). So you can turn `C-x C-s C-c C-a` into a keyboard macro and save it to your emacs init file. I suggest you bind it to `C-c a` in TeX mode. (Keybindings `C-c X`, where `X` is a letter, are reserved for users.)

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-TeX_002dsave_002dquery

Comment: Typically the "exactly one thing" you would bind the key sequence to would be a custom command that firstly saves the TeX document, and then has AUCTeX render it. It's not clear whether you specifically wish to *avoid* that for some reason, or if you just didn't realise it was an option? (As already mentioned, keyboard macros provide a direct solution to what you've actually asked for, however.)

Comment: @giordano IIUC, disabling TeX-save-query will avoid the prompt but also means that the files will *not* be saved.

Comment: For your special purpose (I assume `TeX-command-run-all`) you can also use the following advice: `(advice-add 'TeX-command-run-all :before (lambda (&rest args) (save-buffer)))` in your init file.

Comment: @YoungFrog  No no, the file will be saved without asking to the user (the right command to use is `TeX-save-document`, not `save-buffer`, because it saves all open TeX buffers, not just the current buffer), read the code or test yourself `;-)`

Comment: @giordano You're right, I had mixed up with `tex-offer-save`.

Answer (score 6):

For this special case (save a *TeX buffer before running the compiler), you don't need to define a binding, or advice a function, but just set [`TeX-save-query`](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-TeX_002dsave_002dquery) to nil:

```lisp
(setq TeX-save-query nil)
```

Answer (score 5):

The general way to link multiple key-bindings to a single binding is a Keyboard Macro ([(emacs) Keyboard Macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html#Keyboard-Macros)).

Keyboard macros can either be 'recorded' interactively, or written in elisp (in string or vector format). The easiest way to produce the latter is to use the `kbd` function, so that you can write the keystrokes using the familiar syntax Emacs uses to display them (i.e. the same as you see when using `C-h c` or `C-h k` to ask about a key sequence).

@youngfrog has provided an example of this approach:

```
(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-x C-a") (kbd "C-x C-s C-c C-a"))
```

In this form, the first `kbd` describes the key sequence to bind the command to, and the second `kbd` provides the keyboard macro command that will be called.

As @Giordano points out, you need to make sure this form gets run *after* AucTex is loaded. You can do this by adding it to your `LaTeX-mode-hook`:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'my-latex-mode-hook)

(defun my-latex-mode-hook ()
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map
    (kbd "C-x C-a")
    (kbd "C-x C-s C-c C-a"))
  ;; and other customizations here...
  )
```

You could also wrap the `define-key` form in `(eval-after-load "latex" '(define-key ...))`

## Interactively defining keyboard macros

Keyboard macros are commonly defined ('recorded') interactively. This is often more convenient (especially for cases where no long-term keybinding is required, but you can still do that if you wish to).

To record a keyboard macro:

1. Press `<f3>`
2. Enter your commands (i.e., `C-x C-s` `C-x C-a`) [maybe you actually want `M-x TeX-save-document` here instead of `C-x C-s`?]
3. Press `<f4>`

You can then repeat this command by pressing `<f4>`.

If you want to save this macro for future use, first give it a name:

- enter `C-x C-k n`, and enter a name, eg. "my-tex-run"

You can then insert the macro code in your `.emacs` file:

- `M-x insert-kbd-macro`, and enter the name of the macro

Now you have the code necessary to rebuild your macro:

```
(fset 'my-tex-run
   (lambda (&optional arg) "Keyboard macro." (interactive "p")
       (kmacro-exec-ring-item (quote ("" 0 "%d")) arg)))
```

You can then use this function in a keybinding command:

```
(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-x C-a") 'my-tex-run)
```

This works fine for putting together quick combinations of commands. However, if you can use customization variables (like the answer @Giordano gave), or use actual elisp code, it will be easier to modify your macro if you want to tweak it beyond just duplicating the raw keypresses.

Comment: `(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-x C-a") (kbd "C-x C-s C-c C-a"))` will work too.

Comment: @YoungFrog cool, I didn't know kbd would work like that!

Comment: A couple of comments: you should wrap the `define-key` in an `eval-after-load`; as I said in [a previous comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21726/how-can-i-set-a-key-binding-to-run-two-other-key-bindings#comment33671_21726), it's better to run `TeX-save-document` rather than `save-buffer` (`C-x C-s`).

Comment: Tyler: Strictly speaking, `kbd` returns a keyboard macro, so from that perspective it's a bit odd to differentiate between using `kbd` and using "keyboard macros" (not that interactive recording isn't clearly a different process for producing them).

Comment: @phils point taken. I hadn't made the connection between keyboard macros (interactively defined) and (kbd ...) before, although it's obvious now. They are still quite distinct user interactions (coding vs recording as you go), and from the perspective worth describing separately i think. If you care to make an edit to clarify this relationship feel free!

Comment: Sure thing. Done.

Comment: Another minor nitpicking: the difference between a hook and `eval-after-load` is that the former executes the commands *every time* a new buffer is (re)opened, the latter executes them just once.  For these reasons, a hook is useful to set buffer local variables, `eval-after-load` to set global variables and key-bindings in a mode-specific map, you don't need to rebind it every time you open a buffer `;-)`.  Ah, `TeX-*` hook and mode map are available to all AUCTeX buffers, `LaTeX-*` ones are available only to LaTeX buffers (https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Modes-and-Hooks).

Comment: @giordano yes, but with no noticeable difference to the user. I prefer hooks because they're documented in the AucTex manual, so they are discoverable by new users. eval-after-load requires the user to figure out after *what*, which is often not obvious in complex packages.