# Configuring multiple key bindings

Tags: key-bindings, keyboard-macros

I would like to bind `M-S-up` to `C-u 7 S-up` to move a timestamp a week forward (and `down` for back). A modification of [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/21736/5345) answer resulted in a "Symbol is void" error in Emacs.

I tried modifying the `define-keys` command, but was not successful, as Emacs then stated that "-up" could not follow after "M-S".

How can I configure a keybinding in my `~/.emacs` file to execute `C-u 7 S-up`?

**Update**

I placed the following, modified from the answer linked above, in the scratch buffer and evaluated it:

```
(define-key my-map (kbd "C-u 7 S-up") (kbd "M-S-up"))
```

Emacs returned `Symbol's value as variable is void: my-map`.

Comment: You're *guessing* at the way to describe a key binding. Don't do that. Just like the answer you've linked to advises, ask Emacs with `C-h k` or `C-h c` and then use the syntax it shows you in your `kbd` arguments.

Comment: `C-h k` followed by pressing Meta Shift Up returns `<M-S-up> is undefined`, as expected.

Comment: define-key expects an existing key map, and it looks like you haven't defined my-map anywhere. I suspect you want to use org-mode-map as you are trying to bind this key for org? You also have the (kbd .. ) arguments backwards for what you've described. Finally, you need the <> chars. Try this:  (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<M-S-up>") (kbd "C-u 7 <S-up>"))

Comment: (Unrelated, but I missed it earlier as I as not in Org-mode when I checked: `<M-S-up>` is already mapped in Org-mode, so it's best to choose a different binding.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set a key in a keymap that doesn't exist. In order to use `define-key`, you need to know the name of the keymap you're trying to modify. To add a keybinding to the global keymap, you can use `global-set-key` instead:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-S-<up>") (kbd "C-u 7 S-<up>"))
```

If you want to modify the keybinding only for org-mode, you can use

```
(eval-after-load "org-mode"
  '(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "M-S-<up>") (kbd "C-u 7 S-<up>")))
```

or

```
(defun my-org-hook ()
  (local-set-key (kbd "M-S-<up>") (kbd "C-u 7 S-<up>")))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'my-org-hook)
```

Answer (score 2):

The typical approach would be to bind the key to a command, rather than another key sequence. In your case you want to call `org-shiftup` with an argument. For example:

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<M-S-up>")
   (lambda () (interactive) (org-shiftup 7)))
```

Alternatively you can bind one key sequence to another as in the example you cited. This works for me:

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<M-S-up>") (kbd "C-u 7 <S-up>"))
```

As @Tyler pointed out, when defining keys for a specific mode you generally want to use a mode hook or `eval-after-load` so that the key is not defined until the mode's keymap has been defined.

A few general tips:

- Use `C-h k` to find that S-up is bound to `org-shiftup`.
- Use `C-h f define-key` to read the doc for `define-key`. It looks like you swapped the arguments and may not be familiar with keymaps.
- As noted in the comments, use `C-h k` to see the appropriate key syntax -- when using `up`, you need the `<>`.
- To really understand key maps and key bindings, refer to the Elisp [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Keymaps.html). There is also a great overview on [Mastering Emacs](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/mastering-key-bindings-emacs).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and all the additional information.